# Cached RSS Not rendering correctly in firefox

Tags: firefox, caching, rss

I have a Jekyll blog with Service Worker implemented.

For some reason, after the feed.xml file is cached. Firefox doesn't render the page like it should, it just shows the raw xml file. Using Ctrl+F5 will render the page like a normal rss feed.

If the rss feed is viewed before the cache is made, then the rss also renders fine.

W3C RSS Validator shows that the feed is indeed valid.

Google Chrome shows the feed just fine with the official rss extension, even when the feed is cached. So I'm guessing this is a problem with Firefox..

I also noticed that Firefox caches some files that I didn't specify in Service Worker while Google Chrome doesn't. With the files being sw.js and feed.xml. Is this the expected behavior?

Here's the link to the webpage: https://lumpbloom7.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by using an if conditional to only fetch pages when `event.request.url != "https://yourpage.tld/feed.xml"`